# creating a new variable based on SourcePath

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to restore my nugets one level up. My repo directory points to say for ex. c:\repo\s  and my solutin is in c:\repo\s\src, when I am restoring packages with nuget restore , its restoring the packages at C:\repo\s\src\packages and I would like that to be C:\repo\s\packages. Appreciate your help.

I have the below nuget.config file in C:\repo\s\src directory.

```
$<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\..\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

My Yaml job looks like this

```
$steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.3.0'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: src/myproject.sln
    vstsFeed: '4448b1e2-8ac8-45ef-870c-1ebab90f3348'
    restoreDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'


- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution src/myproject.sln'
  inputs:
solution: src/myproject.sln
vsVersion: 15.0
msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true'
platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I understand you want to change the location that your NuGet packages are restored to, presumably so that they can be shared between multiple solutions. Can you clarify how this relates to the subject of your question, "creating a new variable based on SourcePath"? Do you want this location to be dynamically configured?

Comment: Can you share your nuget restore task?

Comment: You should let us know which restore type are you using, feed? Or nuget.config? Also, why you need create a variable which based on SourcePath? In nuget restore task, it has one argument names `Destination directory`. You can hard code your path there.